# AVI file can not open on windows

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I have implemented simple avi file display video.for my offline object detection.
but my problem is that I am not getting any error but when I debug it I am not getting any display. please guide me.

```
 int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
  {
 cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("S:\MOVIES\English movies\\TANGLED.avi" );
  IplImage* frame;

 while(1) {
 frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
 if( !frame ) break;
 cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
 char c = cvWaitKey(33);
 if( c == 27 ) break;
 }
 cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
 cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
 }
```

also is there any size limitation for video file or it depends on the version of the opencv? my video is for moving human.I am using opencv2.3 in visual studio C++ 2008
Please anyone can guide me?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

An AVI file is really just a container specification and is fairly promiscuous with regards to the vast number of media formats it will accept, however the playback host must have the decoder for all of the media components or, depending on the playback application an error that it can't open/play the video file. You could do several  things to fix this:

- Install a pre-made binary codec for the OS+bittedness playback target,
- Compile whichever codecs you require/want and globally add them the usual way for your OS.
- Find, obtain and/or recreate a.new version with a codec combination which is supported by default by the majority of media players .
- Call the neighborhood  hacker and ask him to convert it to a different format
- Stomp and romp on a crusade to standardize the format of the media components AVI file
- Just use MKV containers or author DVD discs instead. AVI  files are as outdated as rotational media.
- Take up virtual guest farming ... Buy 4 SM15000 Rack clusters, create 10000 VMs , configure supporting infrastructure and use them to take over the world, demand unification then make  pudding for dessert.

More in-depth detail is here :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably the way you are passing the filename to function. Try using double backslash:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("S:\\MOVIES\\English movies\\TANGLED.avi" );
```

and **always test the result of the function**:

```
if (!capture)
{
    printf("!!! Failed to open file.\n");
    return;
}
```